# Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'checkNav' must have exactly one root element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I use meteor+angular, I want use templateUrl in directive to include nav.ng.html
but I throw a error

```
Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'checkNav' must have exactly one root element
```

**index.html:**

```
 5 <body ng-app='checkApp' ng-controller='CheckCtrl'>
 6   <check-nav></check-nav>
 7 </body>
```

**directive.js**

```
  1 angular.module 'checkApp'
  2   .directive 'checkNav', () ->
  3   ┊ restrict: 'E'
  4   ┊ replace: true
  5   ┊ templateUrl: 'client/templates/check-views/nav.ng.html'
```

**nav.ng.html**

```
<div>test</div>
```

how can I fixed it?

Answer (score 5):

This results from the fact the the HTML your directive is rendering (`nav.ng.html`) has sibling elements instead of one that wraps all.

For instance, this will result in the error:

```
<div>One</div>
<div>Two</div>
```

This will be fine:

```
<div>
    <div>One</div>
    <div>Two</div>
</div>
```

So you should fix the HTML to have only one root element and the error will go away.

Comment: I have change my code, I set `<div>test</div>` in `nav.ng.html` it is not OK

Comment: Can you try removing the `replace: true` ?

Comment: but I want to replace ` <check-nav></check-nav>`。。。。。

Comment: I try to remove `replace: true`, it throw error `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.`

Comment: This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15073/   Your example should be the same. Are you sure of the HTML contents?

Comment: you don't understant me.......  please see my example above, I said I can't work with `templateUrl`, I had try work with `template`, it works, But it cant work with `templateUrl`, Can you understant what I mean?

Comment: Now I understand, you haven't said `template` worked before.

Comment: @iChido Awesome, glad I could help.

Comment: I tried definitely wrapping does not seems to be problem. replace false working!! it works for template url with replace false

Answer (score 1):

your **nav.ng.html** should look like this:

```
<div>
  <div>test</div>
</div>
```

if it not works? then **also**  change index.html as:

```
<body ng-app='checkApp' ng-controller='CheckCtrl'>
  <div>   
     <check-nav></check-nav>
  </div>
 </body>
```